# Generate value in seperate thread for TableColumn in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Currently in development for my JavaFX application I've run into a small problem when it comes to populating my Tables. In my current setup I have the following:

```
    infoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures, ObservableValue>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures cellDataFeatures) {
            DataMessage dataMessage = (DataMessage) cellDataFeatures.getValue();

            SimpleStringProperty infoProperty = new SimpleStringProperty("Loading...");

            if (dataMessage != null) {
                if (isMessageNotification(dataMessage)) {
                    Notification notification = getNotificationFromMessage(dataMessage);
                    infoProperty.set(LanguageUtils.getNotificationInfo(dataMessage, notification));
                } else if (isMessageRequest(dataMessage)) {
                    Request request = getRequestFromMessage(dataMessage);
                    infoProperty.set(LanguageUtils.getRequestInfo(dataMessage, request));
                }
            }

            return infoProperty;
        }
    });
```

The calls to LanguageRegistry (My own class), uses some resources in regards to loading different objects relevant to the one specified. This causes my application to freeze for a few seconds to populate the list, as these are notifications and requests they will be coming in real time and as such need to load in the background so it doesn't bug the user.

What I had initially attempted to to is to run the code within "if(dataMessage != null)" in another thread, and set the value of the infoProperty string on the completion of the code execution. Unfortunately this didn't seem to work and the table simply said "Loading..." indefinitely.

So essentially my question comes to the title, I need my cellValueFactory code to run in a seperate thread as to not freeze the application. If something isn't clear in the question let me know and I'll change it.

Comment: Why is there a "DataMessage" in the current CELL VALUE? That doesnt make much sense IMHO - and what are `isMessageNotification` and `isMessageRequest` supposed to be?

Comment: @specializt `DataMessage` is presumably the type of the items in the table: see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html#getValue--). (But I agree it would be better if the OP didn't use raw types.)

Comment: The DataMessage is just an object with a few properties, isMessageNotification/Request checks the type of the DataMessage object then converts the contents from JSON to a Notification or Request.

Comment: literally everybody who is familiar with JavaFX knows that these are table items - but WHY ARE THEY NAMED LIKE THAT? Its like naming an apple "SportsCar", it does not make any sense whatsoever - in fact, noone will be able to understand such a construct. What you're calling "DataMessage" is a TABLE ROW ITEM or perhaps a TABLE CELL or simply a Cell, probably even something like a "CustomCell". Your naming "convention" is highly confusing, misleading and actually lets the reader suspect that you didnt understand your own code .... sorry but its just like that

Comment: Also : why are you "converting contents from JSON"? Yet again : that doesnt make any sense, you dont need to "convert" anything in custom table row items as you can put anything you like in there ...

Comment: @specializt There's no need to get angry, that's not really the most important part of the question. It's just extra information to better explain my data management. The DataMessage object contains some common information across it's child objects which are stored as JSON strings. Essentially just some serialization.

Comment: You clearly have no clue what im talking about. Your design is massively flawed and will never be understood by anyone except yourself, "explaining" thi ngs in code makes no sense.

Comment: @specializt Again, there's no need to be angry. I came here for help, not to be insulted. If you're not interested in helping then simply don't comment, it's not the end of the world that people do things differently than you. If you could see the full context of my program things would make much more sense.

Comment: I think you need to stop taking drugs - that "angry" thing of yours is getting out of hand. Also : there is literally not a single "context" in existence in which it is valid to mix multiple design models, like you're demonstrating. That example basically is model, view AND controller mashed into one giant, convoluted and most likely buggy class. Expect it to be completely replaced once an actual developer is forced to fix your code ... lets just hope it never happens - for his sake

Comment: Actually, I think describing someone who's typing in all caps and writing long responses about how bad someone is at something as angry is a pretty good description.

Not looking for a fight, I asked for some help with an issue. My data management is irrelevant, as shown in the response below I could be pinging a server to check if something in the table is valid and the issue would arise. At this point in the application I'm fiddling with JavaFX more than anything else. I ran into an issue, I tried to fix it, then when I was having trouble I asked for help.

Comment: Yes, your drugs definitely arent good for you - noone is writing in "all caps" here and there are no "long responses". At all. Hey, i think it might be better to come down from your trip before doing communication over the internet .... just a suggestion

Comment: @specializt "Nobody is talking in all caps here." " but WHY ARE THEY NAMED LIKE THAT" - specializt 2015

Comment: Yes, thats somewhat the opposite of "all caps". Its a part of a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the cell value factory to lazily load the data. You can either do this in the model class (`DataMessage`) itself, which looks like this example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BackgroundLoadingTableCell extends Application {

    private static final Random rng = new Random();

    private static final Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t ;
    });

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::valueProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Data", Item::dataProperty));

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(100))).forEach(table.getItems()::add);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }


    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        private final ObjectProperty<String> data = new ObjectPropertyBase<String>() {

            @Override
            public Object getBean() {
                return Item.this;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "data";
            }

            @Override
            public String get() {
                String value = super.get();
                if (value == null) {
                    Task<String> loadDataTask = new Task<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String call() {
                            return getData(Item.this.getValue());
                        }
                    };
                    loadDataTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> set(loadDataTask.getValue()));
                    exec.execute(loadDataTask);
                    return "Loading..." ;
                }
                return value ;
            }

        };

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        private String getData(int value) {
            // simulate long running process:
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250 + rng.nextInt(500));
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            return "Data for "+value ;
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }


        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final ObjectProperty<String> dataProperty() {
            return this.data;
        }


        public final java.lang.String getData() {
            return this.dataProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setData(final java.lang.String data) {
            this.dataProperty().set(data);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

or you can regard the `DataMessage` as the value for this cell, and lazily update the cell in a `cellFactory`:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BackgroundLoadingTableCell extends Application {

    private static final Random rng = new Random();

    private static final Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t ;
    });

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::valueProperty));
        TableColumn<Item, Item> dataColumn = column("Data", item -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Item>(item));

        dataColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Item, Item>() {
            private Task<String> dataLoadTask ;

            @Override
            public void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    setText("Loading...");
                    if (dataLoadTask != null) {
                        dataLoadTask.cancel();
                    }
                    dataLoadTask = new Task<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String call() {
                            return getData(item.getValue());
                        };
                    };
                    dataLoadTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> setText(dataLoadTask.getValue()));
                    exec.execute(dataLoadTask);
                }
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(dataColumn);

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(100))).forEach(table.getItems()::add);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private String getData(int value) {
        // simulate long running process:
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250 + rng.nextInt(500));
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return "Data for "+value ;
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }


    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }


        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }


        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and tried this but it didn't seem to work, but in the process I ran into a new issue. The code inside the call method of the CellValueFactory seems to be called multiple times for one change. You can see what I mean here: http://hastebin.com/urufeyimur.avrasm I get all of that output from one change with a simple print to console for the cellvaluefactory. I'm thinking it might just be a better idea to cache this information then add it to the table.

Comment: I guess when the property is updated, it causes the cell value factory to be invoked again. I think you either need to do the lazy loading of the property in the model class (`DataMessage`) itself, or you can make the cell value the `DataMessage` object itself (`setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<DataMessage>(cellData.getValue()));`), and lazily display the text in a `cellFactory`